# Why do Drupal core functions get node object instead of nid as argument?

Tags: 7

Most (if not all) of Drupal functions accept $node object instead of $nid as argument, like `node_type_get_name($node)`, so we should first write `node_load($nid)` and send its long output to the functions, whereas they can call the `node_load()` function themselves and reduce number of developers' codes. What's the reason?

Comment: Why would you want to load the node again for every single API function? What an incredible slowdown that would be. Loading the object once and passing it around is definitely a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's to avoid the repetition of node_load that could occur.

I searched a little in the source and you can see [node_type_get_name($node)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/calls/node_type_get_name/7) is called from others functions which also take a $node object argument, [node_promote_action](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_promote_action/7) for exemple

```
function node_promote_action($node, $context = array()) {
  $node->promote = NODE_PROMOTED;
  watchdog('action', 'Promoted @type %title to front page.', array('@type' => node_type_get_name($node), '%title' => $node->title));
}
```

It seems [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) to me. Imagine you gave a nid as argument in node_promote_action :

```
function node_promote_action($nid, $context = array()) {
  $node = node_load($nid);
  $node->promote = NODE_PROMOTED;
  watchdog('action', 'Promoted @type %title to front page.', array('@type' => node_type_get_name($nid), '%title' => $node->title));
}
```

And then node_load again in [node_type_get_name](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_type_get_name/7) :

```
function node_type_get_name($nid) {
  $node = node_load($nid); // repetition
  $type = _node_extract_type($node);
  $types = _node_types_build()->names;
  return isset($types[$type]) ? $types[$type] : FALSE;
}
```

With nid as argument, each time a node related function (A) need to process some node's properties (often if not always), they would call node_load. This would lead to unnecessary repetition when another node processing function (B) is called inside the first (A), just like in the above example.